Xcode preview error "Compiling failed: cannot find 'SomeView' in scope"
Xcode (15.4) preview compilation is weird. The following code compiles flawlessly for device or simulator, but fails if compiling for preview:
import SwiftUI

enum Namespace {
    struct View1: View {
        var body: some View {
            Text("Test")
        }
    }
}

extension Namespace {
    struct View2: View {
        var body: some View {
            View1() // Error only if compiling for preview
                    // CompileDylibError: Failed to build ViewX.swift
                    // Compiling failed: cannot find 'View1' in scope
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    Namespace.View2()
}

What's going on here? Why compilation for preview is special?
So far I found two workarounds, either replace View1() with Namespace.View1() or add fileprivate typealias View1 = Namespace.View1, but keeping those in sync quickly gets annoying. Do you have better ideas?

The first is the right way, view1 is a child of namespace

Both View1 and View2 belong to the same Namespace. The question is, why is it working for device or simulator and doesn't work for preview.

Because you are in namespace for the other code, Preview doesn’t know what is inside another object  so you need to specify where it is.

It should be the same Swift compiler for run, test, archive, preview or whatever. But for some reason I don't understand Preview is special.

Previews have always been kind of glitchy. I'm not surprised at all.

Turns out it's bug which is fixed in Xcode 16.

Fixed: Previewing inside of files with methods of types nested in extensions no longer fails. (74739568) (FB9019661)

